# Mysql multiple condition one column subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a table with firms that rent cars, with columns like

```
Firms | Car 
GD1   | CAR1 
GD1   | CAR2 
GD2   | CAR3 
GD3   | CAR4
```

And also other one with the cars rented by the clients, like this:

```
Client | Car Rented
C1     | CAR1
C1     | CAR2
C1     | CAR3
C1     | CAR4
C2     | CAR4
C3     | CAR1
C3     | CAR2
C4     | CAR1
C5     | CAR2
```

I need to know all the clients that rent all the cars from an specific firm.
**The only input that I have is the firm name (for instance GD1)**
If I use GD1 the output should be this one:

```
Client
C1
C3
```

It may seem easy, but I'm really having trouble with this one...

Thanks for the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know whether a client rents all the car from a particular firm, you need to know how many cars owned by the firm and how many cars rented from the firm by the client.
To know how many cars owned by the firm, you can get that by this query:

```
SELECT      Firms, COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_CAR
FROM        FirmTable
GROUP BY    Firms
```

And to know how many cars rented from the firm by the client, you can get by this query:

```
SELECT      Client, Firms, COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_CAR
FROM        FirmTable a
INNER JOIN  ClientTable b ON a.Car = b.Car
GROUP BY    Client, Firms
```

And now you need to get the client that rents all the car, meaning that the NUM_OF_CAR from the first query and the second query must match for the respective firm.
Combining both queries above, you can use:

```
SELECT      DISTINCT Client
FROM        (
            SELECT      Firms, COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_CAR
            FROM        FirmTable
            GROUP BY    Firms
            ) t
INNER JOIN  (
            SELECT      Client, Firms, COUNT(*) AS NUM_OF_CAR
            FROM        FirmTable a
            INNER JOIN  ClientTable b ON a.Car = b.Car
            GROUP BY    Client, Firms
            ) u
ON          t.Firms = u.Firms AND t.NUM_OF_CAR = u.NUM_OF_CAR
WHERE       t.Firms = 'GD1'
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I need, also thanks for the two steps explanation that you edited later. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new at mysql but you can try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client from ClientTable where CarRented=(SELECT Car from FirmTable where Firms='GD1');
```

Comment: Thanks, but have in mind that in this case the subquery will have more than 1 row, so your solution wouldn´t work...